# Backbone.js Collection.create and overridden Model.set

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model where I have changed the set method to calculate extra attributes on every set of the model.

According to the docs this should be the way to call super in order to make sure the model is actually saved.

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
```

And it works just as expected, unless I use Collection.create.

My custom set method gets run, but I think the original does not since the collection remains empty.
The server receives the correct data and sends the right data back. On both occasions my method gets executed, but the collection is still empty.

Can I change the super call to make it work with Collection.create or is there another way to do the same thing?

Comment: Is an exception being thrown along the way, perhaps?  Have you checked your console to make sure this is not the case?

Comment: No exceptions what so ever. That would have made it easier, but sadly it just fails silently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just as I thought, I missed something.
When overriding Model.set() one must put `return this;` at the end.

So a model should look like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    set: function(attributes, options) {
        // Custom code...
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
    }
});
```

Comment: Or, actually, you would simply return the result of the "super" since you are really just overriding it anyways: `return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);`

Comment: If you return this, instead of call to Backbone.Model set method, validation will not work, as it should for that model. It will never return false, what should happen in case of errors during validation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend cracking open a debugger and following it through.  Take a look at the [Collection.create](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-68) function and the [Model.save](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41) function.  Note that the `create` function calls `Model.save` with a `success` callback.  `Model.save` sends the data to the server and also chains to the `success` callback at which `Model.set` is called.

I'd put breakpoints in the `success` callbacks for both of these functions as they are very straight forward and will likely point out your issue.

Finally, if you are able to reproduce the problem with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it would be really useful in helping us understand the full context of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I found it by following your advice. Got to hone my skills in JS debugging and they clearly needed it :)