# How to get an item in a collection with extra attributes

Tags: collections, backbone.js, backbone-views

I currently get an item in a collection for a user like so:

```
me.user = Backbone.Collection.Users.collection().get(id);
```

This returns the default set of attribute required in the app. On the user profile page, I want to show additional attributes that aren't necessary anywhere else.

How can I get an item in a collection (which queries the server) with additional attributes that I can specify?

Thanks

Comment: I'm imagining he means something like a generic user model that has attributes `name` and `email` but one user model might have an additional objects attached like an authentication model to signify that it is THE user user.

Answer (score 0):

So to go along with the comment, what I think you want is to produce extra models instead of creating two user models, one with redundant + extra data.

One way you could do this is to give a relationship between different models.

Say a `user` model consists of simply a name and email. That's fine and dandy but you also want to render a user profile on the page (or whatever 'extras' you intend.) This seems like a good opportunity to create a separate model representing the extra data you desire.

You can do it a few ways. For example, if every user has a profile you could bake it into your user model. Something like when you create a user model:

```
user.profile = new Profile();  // model
```

I've seen some people put other models inside a model's attributes `user.set('profile', new Profile())` but I'm not sure if this is a great idea. I like to keep my model attributes isolated to just that model.

Each profile model would have a url that corresponds to the model.id.

So then you could just user.profile.fetch() and use that profile attributes to populate the data in your view. Maybe it does something like /user/1/profile

Another aspect about your question that I think you might be alluding to is sending data from the server in one go when you fetch the collection. Maybe your server replies with data like this:

```
[{"name":"Jake", "email":"j@stack.com", "profile":"{"aboutme":"Some story"}"}, ... ]
```

and the profile data is only available for those who have it etc. In this case, you can then use the `parse()` function to pull out that extra data out and doing something before sending the name and email attributes through to the model set method.

Although, recently I think I read that using the parse to do stuff with the extra data is bad form. [Override set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607921/backbone-js-collection-create-and-overridden-model-set) So instead of parsing, you might just want to save that for namespacing and then in your overridden set method do something like:

```
set: function(attributes, options) {

    if (!_.isUndefined(this.profile) && attributes.profile) {
        this.profile = new Profile();
        this.profile.set(attributes.profile);
    } else if (attributes.profile) {
        this.profile.set(attributes.profile);
    }

    delete attributes.profile;

    return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
}
```

You can do something similar for really unique users such as the main user using your app. When I instantiate a user model for my app (the one representing user him/herself) I also initialize a few other special models only that user would have (like an auth model for fetching authentication data etc.)

I'm not sure if I hit what you were asking but I hope I hit something.

Answer (score 0):

Is collection an instance already, and I assume so? If so, you should only do:

```
me.user = Backbone.Collection.Users.collection.get(id);
```

I.e. removing the brackets () after collection.